# How to make Ajax refresh an element only if file was changed?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I have .xspf file that my app downloads from server. This file content updates sometimes. How to make Ajax refresh the element as soon as file content has changed?

Now I have refreshing every 1 sec.

view.py

```py
def sign_update(request):
    # get_sign() is the method that takes content of the file
    artist, track = Icecast().get_sign() 
    response_dict = {'artist': artist, 'track': track}
    return render(
        request,
        'sign.html',
        context=response_dict
    )
```

sign_update.js

```js
function sign_update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "sign_update",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#sign").html(data);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    sign_update();
    setInterval('sign_update()', 1000);
});
```

Comment: @madalinivascu, no, it works with brackets

Comment: you need websokets to push the updates to the page

Comment: @madalinivascu would you explain more fully?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are doing is a **pull method**: `setInterval` is not the best idea because it keeps calling your server with or without a change, imagine if you have 1000 users each one of them will send a request to the server every second.

I advise you to use a **push method** such as **SignalR**. [here is a demo for chat that you can do with small number of lines](http://philssignalrdemo.azurewebsites.net/chat)